# Cannot establish SSH connection on Mac Terminal: 4 Bad configuration options

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, macos-bigsur

I want to establish an SSH connection on my Macbook using the following syntax on the terminal:

**ssh user@IP-Address**

However, it gives the following errors:

```
/Users/name/.ssh/config: line 41: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
/Users/name/.ssh/config: line 82: Bad configuration option: usepam
/Users/name/.ssh/config: line 106: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/Users/name/.ssh/config: line 112: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/Users/name/.ssh/config: terminating, 4 bad configuration options

[Process completed]
```

How do I fix this?

*If I should edit my post, to make anything more clear, please leave a comment. I am new to how this works. Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have server-side configuration options (which generally belong in /etc/ssh/sshd_config) in your client-side configuration file.

Compare the man pages for [sshd_config](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) (the server-side config, which includes the `AcceptEnv`, `AuthorizedKeysFile`, `Subsystem`, and `UsePAM` keywords) vs [ssh_config](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) (the client-side config, which doesn't have any of those -- although it does have some related ones, like `SendEnv`, `SetEnv`, and `SessionType` ).